# How to display many set of two values from database in select box in ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I have developed a ayurvedic website with a lot of packages with their package type(like 7days,14 days etc) with their corresponding prices. I have stored the packages in one table in the database and stored their corresponding package types and prices in another table. For each package there will be a number of package types and their prices.

I have a select box as shown below to store the package type of the particluar package and their prices.

```
   <select>
           <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Your Package Type</option>
           <option value="1"> 14 Days - Rs.20000 </option>
           <option value="2">21 Days - Rs.25000</option>
   </select>
```

This select is in a modal window as shown below :

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Enquiry / Booking / Payment</h4>

     </div>

    <div id="contact_form_bg">
    <div class="form_header">


    </div>
    <div class="contact_form body">
    <form action="#contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>

    <li>
    <p class="left">

    <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date" required>
    </p>
    <p class="left">

    <input type="time" name="time" placeholder="Time" required>      
    </p>
    <p class="left">

     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>      
    </p>
    <p class="left">

    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Contact Number" required>  
    </p>
    </li>

    <li>
    <p class="left">
    <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Your Email" required>  

    </p>
    <p class="left">

     <input type="text" name="no-of-people" placeholder="Selected Package">        
     </p>
    <p class="left">


  <select>
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Your Package Type</option>
  <option value="1"> 14 Days - Rs.20000 </option>
  <option value="2">21 Days - Rs.25000</option>
  </select>            
  </p>
   <p class="left">


  <select>
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Gender</option>
 <option value="1">Female</option>
   <option value="2">Male</option>
 </select>           
  </p>


  </li>        

    <li>
   <p class="txtarea-style">
    <textarea cols="46" rows="3" name="comments" placeholder="Message With Us ...."></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
  <input class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" value="Enquiry">
  </p>
  <p>
  <input class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" value="Booking">
  </p>
 <!-- <p>
   <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-submit" >Booking with Payment </a>
  </p>-->

</li>


 </ul>
 </form>  
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

The select box is also shown in the above code.

I want to display all the package types and their prices in the format shown in the select box. I have the id of the particular package and using that id , i want to retrieve all the package types and prices in that select box.

Can anyone suggest how to do this ?

Comment: please specify your need..

Comment: I have already posted  in it !!! I want to display all the package types and prices of a particular package from the database in the select box which is in the modal window.

Comment: so your mean is that in <option></option> you want to populate all info right?

Comment: sss..I want it like that.

Comment: Ok so i have posted answer on basis of that, please check

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an array of package id and combination of package type and its price.

Make an array such as key will be your package id and value would combination of package type and its price.

Example : $selectArray = array('1'=>'14 Days - Rs.20000','2'=>'15 Days - Rs.30000'). like wise.

You can concat days and price using php in array.

After that create loop in view file for select options.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this like this and provide all info at infinite level,

```
<option value="14:20000"> 14 Days - Rs.20000 </option>
```

and when it will be get subbmitted you just need to export it like :

```
$selectedPackageArray = export(':', $_POST['select']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset($con) && !empty($con) && $con!="" ){ // checking the database connection is established or not, here im selecting three fields fro database. the primary key ie the serial no, price and the package name . here im using the id as the value of an option in the to save the database.
        $qryPackage="SELECT id,price,name FROM tablename "; // mysql query to fetch the data.
        if( $strPackageStmt=mysqli_query($con,$qryPackage) )
        {
            while( $strPackageResult=mysqli_fetch_array($strPackageStmt,MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
            {  $ArrPackage[]=$strPackageResult;  }
            if( isset($strPackageResult) ){  unset($strPackageResult);  }
            mysqli_free_result($strPackageStmt);
            if( isset($strPackageStmt) ){  unset($strPackageStmt);  }
        }
    }
    // drawing the select or dropdown using php.
    echo "<select name='package' id='package'>";
        echo "<option value='-1'>Select one package</option>";
        if( isset($ArrPackage) && is_array($ArrPackage) && count($ArrPackage)>0 ) {
            foreach( $ArrPackage as $tempPackage )
            { 
                echo "<option value='". $tempPackage['id'] ."'>". $tempPackage['name'] ."--".$tempPackage['price'] ."</option>";
            }  
        }
    echo "</select>";
```

this is one of the way to populate the select box or drop down using php. please have try on this.This is working on my case.